# Grails with Jquery

Tags: jquery, gwt, grails

Are Grails and Jquery tightly coupled ? If Yes , Are GWT and Grails tightly coupled ? Also what is the best UI framework for Grails in terms of low CPU utilization and best rendering of UI.

Answer (score 2):

No to both, because it's possible to use Grails without jQuery and GWT.

"Best" is so hard to define.  I doubt that anyone will have CPU or rendering data that will apply to your situation.

Comment: Thank you for answering. The CPU issue came because I initially wanted to use Vaadin but found it is very much CPU intensive for application with large number of users. So I was thinking in terms of JQuery but wanted to make sure there is no tight coupling. GWT again has some plus as I am familiar with Java but want to make sure it is not difficult as Vaadin. Another Vaadin issue is tight coupling. Thanks again.